# Running Average in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm new to data analytics. This might be a simple solution but I could not find it after 2 weeks of trying. I have a column of numbers that represent wins and losses. Losses are represented as "0" and wins are represented as "1". Is there a way (an array formula) that I can create a dynamic win rate column? These values to get a running total like how I manually entered them in column B?

```
(w/L , Win %)
(0  ,00)
(1,.50)
(1 .67)
(1 .75)
(0 .60)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1781D5ZNJ4tKzIOhPjrfIW0JRLlbWNUwI6L_4APyYhP8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OytdMXN1ERxlzMZN46DkhUehzE_-Yw0SrOy-WAxd_gQ/edit#gid=0)

In cell E2 there is following formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 SUMIF(
  SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A),1,1,1),"<="&SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A),1,1,1),A2:A)
  /COUNTIF(SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A),1,1,1),"<="&SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A),1,1,1)))
```

With SEQUENCE() we create index column for each of your entry in order to calculate sum of preceding results.

Then using SUMIF() we basically sum all prior results and divide by number of events.

Comment: Oh Thank you....this worked like  a charm!

Comment: I tried using the code in the source data but it would not give me the array formula affect? do you know why?

Comment: In your file formula in column C looks working. Where is the problem?

Comment: When i apply the formula to another sheet it does not work

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kp3vJRjzf4mARJrex1bcRRDwViIxuc_lX8WbL5XZXfI/edit#gid=1518225190

Comment: it does not work in this sheet....is there something special about how sequence works?

Comment: It doesn't count because your values for win/loss - 1/0 are non numeric. Remove quotation marks for 1 and 0
=ARRAYFORMULA( IFERROR( IFS(R2:R="win",1,R2:R="loss",0,R2:R="BE",1),))

Comment: Thank you sir! I don't know how i missed that!! works perfectly